# Domain of a function of two variables

Tags: calculus

$f(x,y)=\sqrt{(8x+8y-4x^2-y^2)}$

I know that $(8x+8y-4x^2-y^2)\ge0$ but I don’t know what to do next. I already tried to factor by their variables which is $4x(2-x)+y(1-y)\ge0$. Could you please help me to continue? I’ve been having a hard time defining domain of a function with two variables.

Comment: Complete the squares

Answer (score -1, accepted):

$$-4(x^2-2x)-(y^2-8y)\ge 0$$ $$4(x^2-2x)+(y^2-8y)\le 0$$ $$4((x-1)^2-1)+(y-4)^2-16\le 0$$ $$4(x-1)^2+(y-4)^2\le 20$$ Geometrically, the domain is the ellipse $$4(x-1)^2+(y-4)^2= 20$$together with its interior.

Answer (score 0):

We have $8x+8y-4x^2-y^2 =  - (2x - 2)^2 - (y^2 - 4)^2 + 20$. Therefore, the domain should be
$$(2x - 2)^2 + (y^2 - 4)^2  \le 20,$$
which is an ellipse.